# Resource 'CMS.Content' is not available on the current site.

Tags: kentico

I get this error in Kentico Administration when I click on Pages tab for a new template

```
Resource 'CMS.Content' is not available on the current site.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the search panel, go to **Modules** and search for the module **Content**. In general CMS.Content will appear as Content on the listing. Now click on sites on your left panel and click **"Add sites"** to select your site. This will make this module available for your website. Sometimes if you do an import into another instance, you need to add the module or whatever was imported into the site.

This process can generally be used to give permission to any module for your website. These modules could be "Media", "Smart Search", "Staging" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a UI permissions error.  I would take a look in Configuration > UI Personalization > Administration and ensure that your account's role has access to CMS > Administration > Content Management.